# Duplicating a file attachment for another model in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I have model `User` with relationships like this:

```
public $attachMany = [
    'logos' => ['System\Models\File', 'delete' => true]
];

public $hasMany = [
    'jobs' => ['Acme\Plugin\Models\Job']
];
```

I also have the following relationship in the `Job` model:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'logo' => ['System\Models\File', 'delete' => true]
];
```

So, a `User` can attach lots of logos and when a user creates a `Job` they can attach one logo to it.

When a `User` creates a `Job` and attaches a logo to it, I need them to be able to choose to attach one of the logos that is already attached to `User` but I don't want it to be the actual relation (ie: **not** a many-to-many type of relationship) but rather a complete duplication of the `File` so that if the user later decided to delete some of their logos at a later date, it wouldn't affect the logo attached to the job.

I have theoretically solved this and answered my own question, but it's quite messy and I can't help but think there may be a simpler way.

```
    // Get the File model
    $chosenLogo = \System\Models\File::find(1);

    // Save the contents of the file to local storage
    Storage::disk('local')->put('tempLogos/' . $chosenLogo->disk_name, $chosenLogo->getContents());

    // Get the job
    $job = \Acme\Plugin\Models\Job::find(34);

    // Create a new File and specify path for data
    $file = new \System\Models\File;
    $file->data = base_path('storage/app/tempLogos/' . $chosenLogo->disk_name);

    // Save file then attach logo to job
    $file->save();
    $job->logo()->add($file);
```

It works, but it's a lot of messing about. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Your question solve my problem on "how to duplicate file model". Sorry to not help with your issue, but thanks for your code of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use MorphTo relations: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#polymorphic-relations
You can create Logo model and morph it to User and to Job models.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about how to duplicate a file attachment (https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments) in October CMS which means both the relationship and the file physically stored on the local or cloud filesystem. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution can be with Behaviors. Extending the `\System\Models\File` class with a `clone()` or `copy()` method, with this:

```
public static function clone(){
    Storage::disk('local')->put('temp/' . $this->disk_name, $this->getContents());
    // Create a new File and specify path for data
    $file = new \System\Models\File;
    $file->data = base_path('storage/app/temp/' . $this->disk_name);

    // Save file then attach logo to job
    $file->save();

    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easier way, your solution is a correct way of storing a physically duplicate of an already stored file on disk and record a new `\System\Models\File` in the database of this duplicate.